# How to access the timer value once the timer task is cancel and resume it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have activity A and B. When I pause the timer in activity A, it stops the timer and I want to resume it again when I start resume button in activity B. I have seen tutorials, but I have just found tutorials within the same activity.

Activity A have the Countdown timer and the Pause button:

```
    // implements CountdownTimer
    final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        TextView timeLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_left_value);

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeft.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
        //  TODO: set intent to next screen
        Intent i = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
    }.start();


    // Pause Button
    Button pause_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_btn);
    pause_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Move to the next view!
            Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivity(i);
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });
```

Activity B have the resume button:

```
    Button resume_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume_btn);
    resume_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Move to the next view!
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: pass the `timeLeft` to activity B using Intent and start Timer in Activity B

Comment: Could you please show, coz I was not able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If have not misunderstood you could add do the following thing:

1. keep track of the "time" and return it before cancelling it:

   ```
   private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
           TextView timeLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_left_value);
           private long  millisUntilFinished = -1;
           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               timeLeft.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
               this.millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;
           }

           public long getMillisUntilFinished() {
             return millisUntilFinished;
           }

           public void onFinish() {
             millisUntilFinished = -1;
           //  TODO: set intent to next screen
           Intent i = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
           startActivity(i);
           }
       }



   final MyCountDownTimer timer = new MyCountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
   ```
2. before starting `ActivityB`, cancell the time and call `timer.getMillisUntilFinished()`, put the value inside the Intent and pass it to `ActivityB`
3. if the `value != -1`, do your math, create a new `CountDownTimer` and start it with the new values

Edit: point 2 example:

```
pause_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Move to the next view!
            Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            i.putExtra("time_left",timer.getMillisUntilFinished());
            startActivity(i);
            timer.cancel();
        }
});
```

Comment: On writing the private void(3rd line), I am getting the error "void is an invalid type for the variable millisUntilFinsihed"

Comment: sorry I meant to write long instead of void

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to follow step 2 and step 3. I try to do this in activity A http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z6qUApQt

Comment: the pastbin is not longer available

Comment: I get an error : The method getMillisUntilFinished() is undefined for the type countdown timer. HINT: Add cast to timer.

Comment: Do you mean I have to create a new class for countdown time now ? Coz now I get HINT: create class..

Comment: But then I have to deal with another activity, which is the CountdownTimer activity. I am getting a bit lost now !

Answer (score 0):

on Activity A

```
pause_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Move to the next view!
            Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            i.putExtra("time_left",timeLeft);
            startActivity(i);
            timer.cancel();
        }
});
```

on Activity B

```
long timeLeft = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("time_left");

Button resume_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume_btn);
resume_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeft , 1000) {
                       //your code
                }.start();
    }


                finish();
           }
});
```